# ScriptDb Query of a date and sort by descending order

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following query running from a Script Db.  I'm storing the date it's looking for as 'M/d/yyyy', as a string.  The lookUp is fine and returns all that I need but the sort order is not by month or year.

```
var result = db.query({"p1arSn":e.parameter.search}).sortBy("maintAccomplishedDate", db.DESCENDING);
```

Any guidance appreciated Thanks!

Comment: Just a thought. If you could store your date string as yyyy-mm-dd then sorting would be much simpler. Have a great one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use sortBy to sort on dates stored as strings. Your options are

1. to retrieve the unsorted data, copy it into an array, and use array.sort() yourself, or
2. to change what you are storing in ScriptDb.

Option 1 is simpler but if you are retrieving paged or limited data, then doing the sort after the retrieval is not what you are going to want.

Option 2 is a little harder - when storing a date in ScriptDb, store the timestamp (Date has a `getTime()` that gives you that). Those are numbers that can be sorted on.

You can get a timestamp from one of your date strings like this:

```
var timestamp = new Date('3/5/1983').getTime()  // 415688400000
```

You can get the original string back like this:

```
var d = new Date(415688400000);
var string = [d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDate(), d.getYear()].join('/');
```

Comment: Thanks alot Corey.. I'm new to scripting period, and still grasping best practices for coding.  I'll redo the data base that way.  Correct me if I'm wrong but I should just be able to loop through each record in scriptDb and update the "maintAccomplishedOn" property correct?